# Insert records with lookup field from apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, soql

### Object :- MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c (parent conversation)

field 1 :- MBT_SFFB__Author_URL__c www.xxxxxxx.com

field 2 :- MBT_SFFB__External_ID__c 152522525252 // id of the URL

field 3 :- MBT_SFFB__Parent__c = Lookup to MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c

---

### Object :- MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c (child conversation)

field 1 :- MBT_SFFB__Author_URL__c blank

field 2 :- MBT_SFFB__External_ID__c 12122122212

field 3 :- MBT_SFFB__Parent__c = Lookup to MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c

---

```
List<MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c> objconversationlst = new List<MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c>();  //contians all the records conversation parent or child.
```

Wanna insert both records with lookup field of parent - child. How can i insert ??

Comment: In 1 list you cannot insert as there will be a race condition. You need to insert the Parent first and then insert the child records.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the External Id must already be known to the database before you can reference it, so you can't have a parent and child of the same type in the same list in the same DML operation.

You can do things like Accounts and Contacts, because the system goes through an automatic "chunking" mode where the accounts will happen before the contacts. When there's no such demarcation within the data, the system simply fails.

I did come up with a working example where we still use *one list*, but we have to perform *two* DML operations anyways (in other words, you don't "save" any governor limits this way).

Here's some code I ran in execute anonymous as proof.

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[] {
    new Account(Name='Test',External_Id__c='12345'),
    new Account(Name='Child Test',Parent=new Account(External_Id__c='12345'), External_Id__c='22558')
};
Database.insert(accounts, false);
Database.insert(accounts, false);
```

In the first insert statement, the parent is created and the child errors out, and in the second insert statement, the child is created and the parent errors out (because it already has an Id).

It's not particularly elegant, but it is functional. If you're looking to insert parents and children, it's best to have two (or more) lists, and insert them in sequence, or even better, insert all of the records without their parent fields populated, then perform an update with the parent values populated. This last technique would use the least number of DML statements and row operations regardless of data complexity.